# Java Process object fails to execute given command

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run a piece of Python code via a Java application. The command when put directly into Command Prompt cd'd to the working directory runs exactly as intended. However, my attempts to use the Runtime and ProcessBuilder classes in conjunction with the Process class has yielded no sign of correct function which would be the creation of a CSV file for every call of the code.

I am running this program using Intellij on Windows 10. I have added each directory I am using to my environmental PATH variable as well as attempting full paths in my commands and just file names. The only source of life I can find is that if I include a `.waitFor()` method a `.isAlive()` method will return true before the `.waitFor()` method is called. 
I have searched through various similar questions and concluded that using a ProcessBuilder object is the best way to go and that the biggest issue is probably the structure of my command. However, I have made many iterations and have found nothing that changes the caught error to anything useful.

Here is the privacy augmented code that I have been running, I wrote out the command in full in the process builder as that is the last iteration I have attempted.

```
            for (int y = 1; y < iterator; y++) {
                try {

                    String command =
                            "C:\\Users\\myName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python C:\\Users\\myName\\IdeaProjects\\projectApplication\\script.py ";
                    String pythonInputPath = " C:\\Users\\myName\\IdeaProjects\\projectApplication\\bin\\output" + y + ".wav ";
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command+Arrays.toString(pythonCommandString).replaceAll("\\s","")+pythonInputPath+Integer.toString(y));
                    Process p = pb.start();

                    //Process checks
                    System.out.println(p.isAlive());
                    p.waitFor();
                    System.out.println(p.isAlive());

                    //Destroying process once complete to ensure smooth iterations
                    p.destroy();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Problems with python script execution: " + ex);
                }
            }
```

They python code takes in a WAV file (pythonInputPath) that is a product of earlier part of the application, an `Integer[]` that usually includes ~20 values (`pythonCommandString`), and a single iteration integer (y).

The first call to `.isAlive()` is true and the second is false as expected however the script normally creates a CSV that should be output to a bin file that exists in the working director and that fails to occur when running from Java. From other examples I expected using the Process builder as opposed to the Runtime stream to work, however, there is no difference in my implementation.

Comment: What exit code was returned by `Process.waitFor()`?

Comment: I believe the code overall returned exit code 0. I am not sure about the method itself. The answer by igorpst fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **not** concatenate the program with its arguments. Quoting [Oracle ProcessBuilder docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

> Each process builder manages these process attributes: a command, a
>   list of strings which signifies the external program file to be
>   invoked and its arguments, if any

and

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
```

Just use the constructor you use, but pass each argument as a separate string, otherwise the OS will try to find an application that is named as a whole command line you gave, and obviously there is no such program

Comment: I made the appropriate changes to that line of code. The build took longer to run however still failed to execute properly. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Never I had an extra white space. It works. I thought I had tried this but I must have not checked over the paths well enough when I did that. Thank you for being steadfast that this should work.